# How write list files into csv

Tags: python, list

I wish to write the list files into a csv file:

```
a = ['0.18 man::-1_-1king|new\n', '0.19 gif::-2manchester\n', '0.177 united\n']
```

How can I do it?

Here are my codes :

```
import csv

a = ['0.18 king\n', '0.19 manchester\n', '0.177 united\n']

with open("output.csv",'wb') as resultFile: 
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile)
    wr.writerows(a)
```

I wanted my results to be something like this:

```
Column 1    Column 2
0.18            man::-1_-1king|new
0.19            gif::-2manchester
0.177           united
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916542/writing-list-of-strings-to-excel-csv-file-in-python#6916576).

Comment: with open("output.csv",'wb') as resultFile:
            wr = csv.writer(resultFile)
            wr.writerows(l)

this I tried but the results are very weird

Comment: I tried it but results became every character in each column instead of whole word in one column.

Comment: Please edit your question: add the code that you've tried, the expected result and the result that you got. It will make it easier to answer the question that way.

Comment: sorry i mean wr.writerows(a)

Comment: Is python 2 or python 3? Also, what do you expect the csv file to look like? Are you aware that the file will only have a single column?

Comment: I am using python 3. I wanted it to be like in column 1 : 0.18 column 2: king...... for each row

Comment: Please [edit] your expected result into the question.

Comment: I have edited it. thank you

Comment: @JJson  [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51517417/7053679)

Comment: thanks but I dont understand how he get data2.

Answer (score -1):

If its a simple list as shown in the example, you don't need to import csv, just try this

```
a = ['0.18 king\n', '0.19 manchester\n', '0.177 united\n']

with open("output.csv",'wb') as fin: 
    for row in a:
        word1, word2 = row.split()
        fin.write('%s,%s\n'%(word1,word2))

a = ['0.18 man::-1king\n', '0.19 gif::-2manchester\n', '0.177 united\n']

with open("output.tsv",'wb') as fin: 
    for row in a:
        word1, word2 = row.split()
        fin.write('%s\t%s\n'%(word1,word2))
```

Comment: What if one of those words contains a comma? Use the csv module to write csv files, damnit.

Comment: Yea, I have commas so somehow everything printed in according to the columns but when I have commas then it became weird. Any other alternative and thank you

Comment: I edited and include another new example when something like comma included.

Comment: Well then you probably have to use csv module unless you are ok with a tsv file (tab separated file), in which case only a small modification is necessary

Comment: is it possible to make it in csv file? I would like to learn as well to understand how it works

Comment: Thank you and the previous one works but however, I tried another new problem. What about if my list contains "_"? I edited again and could you please take a look?

Comment: @JJson I don't see how an underscore could cause any problems. If you want to be tricky, add some commas and/or quotes in your data.

Comment: I tried to save it in csv file but when it happens to have the underscore. Somehow words after underscore being inserted into next column instead of the same column

Comment: @JJson Then there's something wrong with the program you're using to read the csv file. Maybe it thinks that the underscore is the separator.

Comment: But I am using normal program like microsoft to open it in excel

Comment: @JJson [There's nothing wrong with the csv.](https://repl.it/repls/UselessBisquePyramid)